# How to copy a file in a zipfile into a certain directory?

Tags: python, zip

I need only one subfile in each of 500 zipfiles, the paths are the same, like:

```
120132.zip/A/B/C/target_file
212332.zip/A/B/C/target_file
....
```

How can I copy all these target files into one directory? Keeping the entire paths in the new directory will be the best, which I mean is:

```
target_dir/
    120132/A/B/C/target_file
    212332/A/B/C/target_file
    ......
```

I tried it with Python modules *zipfile* and *shutil*

However, **copyfile** from *shutil* takes the entire path as argument but when I tried to directly copy the target file it will raise filenotfind error. When unzipped by the zipfile.Zipfile, the target file will be accessible but *copyfile* becomes invalid.

How can I do this correctly and efficiently ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ZipFile.extract`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) accepts optional `path` specifying into which directory it will extract file:

```
import os
import zipfile

zip_filepath = ['120132.zip', '212332.zip', ...]  # or glob.glob('...zip')
target_dir = '/path/to/target_dir'

for path in zip_filepath:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as zf:
        dirname = os.path.join(
            target_dir, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
        )
        zf.extract('A/B/C/target_file', path=dirname)
```

Comment: Yes! That's totally what I want! extract() makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I run into another problem. I executed "zf.extract(r"A\B\C\filename", ..)" on windows, but it failed, saying "There is no item named 'A\\\\B\\\\C\\\\filename'". Could you give me an advice? @falsetru

Comment: @Spike, Are you sure all zip files contains that file? Does it fail from the very beginning file? You may need to check it before calling `extract` or use `try ... except ...`.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I made a mistake, nevertheless, thanks! @falsetru